# Question about an inductive step

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Below is a proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass by induction.

Let $A$ be an infinite bounded sequence of reals. Then $A$ has a limit point $l$. Let $a \in A$. Then $\exists a_i \in N_{r}(l)$ for all $r > 0$. In other words, $0< |l - a| < r$ for all $r > 0$.

In particular,  $0< |l - a| < 1$ holds meaning there must be some index $k_1$ for which $0< |l - a_{k_1}| < 1$.

Suppose $0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac 1j$ for all $j:= 2, 3, \ldots, n.$

By definition of $l$, we also have $0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$ for $j \in \{2,\ldots, n\}$. Because $|N_r(l)| = \infty$ for any $r > 0, \ 0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$ holds for infinite number of $k_j$. So far, out hypothesis asserts $0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$ is true only for finite number of $k_j$. Thus there's some $k_{n+1}$ s.t. $|l - a_{k_{n+1}}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$. By well-ordering property, we can also assert that $k_{n+1}$ must be the least element of $\{k_m\}_{m=1}^\infty \setminus \{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n\}$ that follows after $k_n$.

My question: does the justification above for the existence of $k_{n+1}$ work? In general, does that proof above make sense?

Comment: It seems like you are assuming that $A$ has a limit point. Isn't that what you are trying to prove?

Comment: I am proving $A$ has a subsequence that converges to $l$.

Comment: So you are assuming that $A$ has a limit point and proving that there exists a subsequence converging to $A$? (If so that's OK, but it is not really what Bolzano-Weirstrass states)

Comment: $A$ is an infinite bounded set of reals and so it has at least one limit point. It's a theorem. If $l$ is a limit point of $A$, then there's some $\{a_k\} \subseteq A$ s.t. $a_k \to l.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple problems with your proof. Let me go through it.

The claim you are proving is the following one:

> Let $A$ be an infinite bounded sequence of reals. Then $A$ has a limit point $l$. Let $a \in A$. Then $\exists a_i \in N_{r}(l)$ for all $r > 0$. In other words, $0< |l - a| < r$ for all $r > 0$.

There are some problems though. First, there's a typo and $|l-a|$ should be $l-a_i$. Also, you do not seem to be using $a\in A$ at all in that statement. Also saying $0<|l-a|<r$ a **for all $r>0$** is a bit problematic as one might confuse it with the impossible statement that the number $|l-a|$ is a non zero number smaller than any positive number. I would therefore rewrite the claim as

Claim: Let $A$ be an infinite bounded sequence of reals, and let $l$ be a limit point for $A$. Namely, for every $r>0$ there exists $a_i\in A$ so that $a_i\in N_r(l)$. In other words, $0<|l-a_i|<r$.

> In particular,  $0< |l - a| < 1$ holds meaning there must be some index $k_1$ for which $0< |l - a_{k_1}| < 1$.

So far so good. I would add however that you can write $A$ as a sequence $\{a_1,a_2,...\}$.

> Suppose $0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac 1j$ for all $j:= 2, 3, \ldots, n.$

I would write, fix $n\geq 1$ and assume inductively that there exists $a_{k_j}\in A$, $j=1,2,...,n$ so that $0<|l-a_{k_j}|<\frac{1}{j}$. Since here you use a claim by induction it may make sense to include another assumption. Namely there exists such $a_{k_j}$'s **and $k_1<k_2<...<k_n$.**

> By definition of $l$, we also have $0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$ for $j \in \{2,\ldots, n\}$.

That does not seem to be true, how did you come up with that?

> Because $|N_r(l)| = \infty$ for any $r > 0, \ 0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$ holds for infinite number of $k_j$.

This sentence is problematic because we have only defined a finite sequence $k_j$. What you really want to write is: Because $|N_r(l)|=\infty$ for any $r>0$, taking $r=\frac{1}{n+1}$ we have that $0<|l-a|<\frac{1}{n+1}$ holds for infinitely many $a\in A$. Note however that the fact that $|N_r(l)|=\infty$ may require a proof.

> So far, out hypothesis asserts $0< |l - a_{k_j}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$ is true only for finite number of $k_j$. Thus there's some $n_{k+1}$ s.t. $|l - a_{k_{n+1}}| < \frac {1}{n+1}$.

I would delete the first sentence, and change the second to: Thus there's some $k_{n+1}$ s.t. $0<|l-a_{k_{n+1}}|<\frac{1}{n+1}$.

> By well-ordering property, we can also assert that $k_{n+1}$ must be the least element of $\{k_m\}_{m=1}^\infty \setminus \{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n\}$ that follows after $k_n$.

You can use it, but since I have assumed that $k_1<k_2<...<k_n$ you no longer have to (note that you need that anyway). Instead you can say that since $N_r(l)$ is infinite for $r=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{k_n}\}$ is finite, there must exists $k_{n+1}>k_n$ so that $a_{k_{n+1}}\in N_{\frac{1}{n+1}}(l)$.

Comment: "That does not seem to be true, how did you come up with that?" Well, $0 < |l - a_{k_j} | < r$ for any $r > 0$. Then we can take one of these $r$ to be $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh no! then you have misunderstood something important. It is important to read the statement the correct way. It says "For every $r>0$, there exists $a\in A$ so that $0<|l-a|<r$", in contrast with "there exists $a\in A$ so that for every $r>0$, $0<|l-a|<r$. Note that the second statement is impossible (its always false, no number can be strictly greater than zero and still smaller than $r$ for all $r>0$)

Comment: $|l - a_{k_j}| < r$ for **any** $r > 0$ means the distance from $l$ to $a_{k_j}$ is less than any positive real whatsoever. It doesn't assert anything about the existence of $a$.

Comment: $|N_r(l)| = \infty$ for any positive $r$ is a theorem $2.20$ on p.$32$ of "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin. Third edition.

Comment: @user1097750 Still, the problem is elsewhere. It is impossible that $0<|l-a_{k_j}|<r$ for any $r>0$. Just try to come up with an example of $l$ and $a_{k_j}$ satisfying this property. If $l=2$, say, what is $a_{k_j}$?

Comment: How about the following? There's some $a_i$ with $0 < |l - a_i| < r$ for any $r > 0$. In particular, there's some $a_i$ with $0 < |l - a_i| < \frac{1}{n+1}$. We just need to prove this $a_i$ is $a_{k_{n+1}}$. But $a_{k_{n+1}}$ exists because $|N_r(l)| = \infty$.

Comment: @user1097750 There's still the same problem and I am not able to explain it. I'll try again. Forget about limit points, forget about calculus and forget about anything else. The sentence "There is some $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<|l-a_i|<r$ for any $r>0$" is always false. Namely, you will never be able to find $l,a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying this condition.

Comment: By definition, $l$ is a limit point of $A$ **if** $\forall r>0, \ N_r(l) \cap A \ne \varnothing \text{ and } \ne \{l\}.$ For example, consider $X = (-2, 2)$. By defn, $2$ is a limit point of $X$ because no matter what radius you take around $2, \ N_r(2)$ will contain something from $X$ since $2 - \epsilon \in X$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$ In other words, $0 < |2 - (2 - \epsilon)| < r$ for any $r > 0$.

Comment: @user1097750 You got the definition right and $2$ is indeed the limit point of $X$. However, the last sentence "in other words" is fase, because $|2-(2-\varepsilon)|=\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ is not smaller than any $r>0$, indeed, it is not smaller than $r=\varepsilon/2$!

Comment: @user1097750 note also that "$\forall_{r>0}, N_r(l)\cap A\not = \emptyset$" is equivalent to "for all $r>0$, there exists $a\in N_r(l)\cap A$", which is equivalent to "for all $r>0$ there exists $a\in A$ so that $0<|l-a|<r$". The whole confusion is about the order, while this sentence is true, the sentence "there exists $a\in A$ so that $0<|l-a|<r$ for all $r>$" is wrong. (It is extremely important to understand these differences, they play huge role in any course in calculus)